# Is possible update equal heights constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I have a ViewController in my objective-c application.
In this UIVIew I have two views with de same height like:[image]

I'm trying set the constant to 0 but this not change with this code:

```
self.firstViewHeightConstraints.constant = 0;
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

I have the priority of heigh equals to 750 and the priority of up view constraint to 250.

I want not apply equals height in a case so, How can I set the height constant constraints of the up view to 0 for hide the first UIView?

Comment: is it not working or what is your question?

Comment: Thanks for yout reply @MilanNosáľ , hope be clear then edit. My code not works, so my question is: How can I set to 0 the constraints for not apply "equals height" constraints on a specific case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not apply the equal heights constraint, keep a reference to it, and simply deactivate it. So something like:

```
self.equalHeightsConstraint.isActive = false
```

Or in ObjC:

```
[self.equalHeightsConstraint setActive:NO];
```

Comment: Your reply help me a lot of, but isActive is for check the status. Should be active or setActive instead of isActive: [self.equalHeightsConstraint setActive:NO];  Thanks!